# Скролл к началу при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда делаешь refresh страницы надо чтобы перекинуло на самый вверх.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот js код, который кидает вверх

```js
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
```

Можете в html вставить после body код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
</script>
```